# how to automatically change or populate the 2nd field based on the value being input in first field?

Tags: jquery

how to automatically populate or change the value of the 2nd readonly field based on the real time input in the 1st input field ?

```
<input id="1stfield" name="1stfield" value="" readonly/>
<input id="2ndfield" name="2ndfield" value="" />


$('#1stfield').change(function(){

// ?

});
```

Comment: but you made your first field as read only.Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `keyup` instead of `change` event to *reflect* the change as you type in field two in field one. Bind keyup on second on second field where you want to type the text and set the value of readonly field which is the first one.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YCFWf/)**

```
$('#2ndfield').keyup(function () {
    $('#1stfield').val($('#2ndfield').val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#1stfield').on('keyup',(function(){

    $('#2ndfield').attr('value',$(this).val());

});
```

Comment: it only changes the value of the 2nd field after i pointed to mouse outside the 1st field, how bout "as I type in the 1st field it will change the 2nd field" ?

Comment: @sasori hey please check my answer again

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#1stfield').keyup(function(){

 $('#2stfield').val($('#1stfield').val());

});
```

Comment: it only changes the value of the 2nd field after i pointed to mouse outside the 1st field, how bout "as I type in the 1st field it will change the 2nd field" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#2ndfield').keypress(function(){
    $('#1stfield').val($('#2ndfield').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="field1" value="111">
<input class="field2" value="111" autofocus>
<input class="field3" value="111" >

$input = $('input');

$input.keypress(function() {
    // Puts the value of the field typed in in ALL other fields
    // regardless of if there are contents in them  
    $input.not(this).val(this.value);
});
```

try this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are discouraged here.